# Adding users in security tab for folder sharing

Tags: security, shared-directory

I have created a powershell script for Folder sharing with GUI. But now even if I did adding users in folder permission the folder is not shared. I found that users need to be added in the security also.
I have came across with so searching but can't get it.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The community cannot develop the whole project for you. Once you have started on a solution, you can ask a specific question if have problem with your code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you for your reply... 
I found the solution. this is the one was searching...........


$acl = Get-Acl $NetworkSharePath
$rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Administrators","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule)
Set-Acl $NetworkSharePath $acl

Comment: Great .... you can write your own answer and post the formatted code. Better than putting it in a comment.

Comment: sure.... i will 

thank you